# send text from MDTextField for an "already executed" function in other file - Python KivyMD

Tags: python, kivy, logic, kivymd

In my 'nov.py' file, I have a function called 'def call_efd_icms(self,dado)' that is executed when the button from 'nov.kv' file is pressed. This function 'call_efd_icms' will send an file path to a second python file called 'process_efd_icms.py' AND ALSO update the current screen to a screen called 'scr 3' (all that in the same function). Then, after that. In the 'process_efd_icms.py' file, in the last lines of code (the above lines don't matter) it sends two variables called 'df_a' and 'df_b' to the first python file called 'nov.py', to a function called 'def parte_pandas(self,df_a,df_b,dado):'. What I having trouble is:

In this scr 3 the user can make a question using an input text (MDTextField, as many times as he wants), this questions will be processed by the function 'def parte_pandas', where will exist a pandas AI code to 'read' the user question and search in the two variables df_a and df_b. With the existing code I am obviously getting the 'required positional argument' error because the 'text' variable doesn't even exist yet in the current code logic.

PYTHON FILE 1 (nov.py)

```
import ...

class ContentNavigationDrawer(BoxLayout):
    screen_manager = ObjectProperty()
    nav_drawer = ObjectProperty()
class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file('nov.kv')
    def call_efd_icms(self,dado):
        from process_efd_icms import EFD_ICMS
        filter = "Text File (*.txt)"
        efd_icms_file_path = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilenames(filetypes=[("Text Files", "*.txt")])
        if not efd_icms_file_path:
            return
        # send the file path to 'process_efd_icms' and update the screen
        EFD_ICMS(efd_icms_file_path,dado)
        if dado == '1':
            if EFD_ICMS:
                self.root.ids.screen_manager.current = 'scr 3'
            else:
                return IOError
        else:
            pass
    def call_efd_pis(self,dado):
        #same thing from the function above
    def call_ecd_icms(self,dado):
        #same thing from the function above
    def call_ecd_pis(self,dado):
        #same thing from the function above


    #the next step after the process_efd_icms
    def parte_pandas(self,df_a,df_b,text):
        #need to get the text from an input on scr 3 that will be used with the df_a and df_b variables
        pass
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

PYTHON FILE 2 (process_efd_icms.py)

```
def EFD_ICMS(icms_path,dado,batch_size=20):
    data = ''

    def FormatarData(variavel, num):
        global data
        data = variavel[num][:2] + '/' + variavel[num][2:4] + '/' + variavel[num][4:]
        return data

    icms_list = icms_path

    # create an empty workbook
    wb = Workbook()

    # create two empty spreadsheets
    ws_a = wb.create_sheet("0000")
    ws_b = wb.create_sheet("0150")

    # create two empty dataframes
    df_a = pd.DataFrame()
    df_b = pd.DataFrame()

    #some code here for progress bar....

                    with open(replace_icms_str, 'r', encoding="latin-1") as file:
                        cont_0000 = {}
                        cont_0150 = {}
                        for line in file:
                            first_six_chars = line[:6]
                            if '|0000|' in first_six_chars:
                                #some code here
                                # Create a new row in the dataframe using the columns list as the values
                                row_a = pd.DataFrame(cont_0000, index=[0])
                                # Concatenate the row to the dataframe
                                df_a = pd.concat([df_a, row_a])
                            elif '|0150|' in first_six_chars:
                                #some code here
                                row_b = pd.DataFrame(cont_0150, index=[0])
                                df_b = pd.concat([df_b, row_b])

                except FileNotFoundError as e:
                    print(f"Arquivo não encontrado: {path}")
                    return
                except PermissionError as e:
                    print(f"Erro de permissão ao acessar o arquivo: {path}")
                    return
                except IOError as e:
                    print(f"Erro de E/S ao abrir o arquivo: {path}")
                    return

    #some code here for progress bar....

    if dado == '1':
        #if dado equal to 1 I need to send the df_a and df_b variables to the parte_pandas function
        from nov import MyApp
        app = MyApp()
        app.parte_pandas(df_a,df_b)
        return True
    else:
        #some code here
```

KIVY FILE (nov.kv)

```
<ContentNavigationDrawer>:
    ScrollView:
        MDList:
            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Exportação Simples Excel"
                on_press:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "main_screen_activity"
            OneLineListItem:
                text: "Porwer BI"
                on_press:
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                    root.screen_manager.current = "bi_init_screen_activity"
Screen:
    MDTopAppBar:
        id: toolbar
        #some code here
    MDNavigationLayout:
        x: toolbar.height
        ScreenManager:
            id: screen_manager
            Screen:
                name: "main_screen_activity"
                MDBoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    pos_hint: {"top": 0.9}
                    MDBoxLayout:
                        orientation:'horizontal'
                        size_hint_y: 0.9
                        MDFlatButton:
                            #some code here
                            on_press: app.call_efd_icms('0')
                        #some code here
            Screen:
                name: "bi_init_screen_activity"
                MDBoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    #some code here
                    MDBoxLayout:
                        orientation:'horizontal'
                        size_hint_y: 0.9
                        MDFlatButton:
                            #some code here
                            on_press: app.call_efd_icms('1')
                        #some code here
            Screen:
                name: 'scr 3'
                id: scr_3_screen
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'horizontal'
                    id: boxLayout_up_scr3
                    # here I need an input field so user can make a question, then I need to retrieve it on parte_pandas function located on file nov.py
                    MDTextField:
                        name: 'my_input_text_field'
                        halign:'center'
                        mode: 'round'
                        icon_right: 'magnify'
                        hint_text: 'Make a question'
                        on_text_validate: app.parte_pandas(self)
        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer
            ContentNavigationDrawer:
                screen_manager: screen_manager
                nav_drawer: nav_drawer
```

I tried sending the df_a and df_b to another def function where I could get the textfield but doesn't seems to work too (at least in the way I had written it).

Answer (score 0):

In your `EFD_ICMS()` method the line:

```
app = MyApp()
```

creates a new instance of `MyApp`. That new instance will not have any access to anything that has happened with the original instance of `MyApp` that is created by the lines:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

I suspect that you actually want the `app` in the `EFD_ICMS()` to reference the original instance. You can accomplish that by using:

```
app = App.get_running_app()
```

instead of creating a new instance of `MyApp`.

Comment: oh thx, I didn't know that! But I still getting an error in passing the text from text field in parte_pandas function